# Scrapy get data from a table always null

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, tags

I was try to get the test or data from table using scrapy. But the table doesn't have a class. the part of structur HTML is like this :

```
<div class="content_e">
    <div class="content-ranklist">
        <div class="rank-title"><span><h1><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Beijing gourmet restaurant
            </font></font></h1></span><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Updated on November 20th</font></font>
        </div>
        <section class="ranklist-table">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="th-label-0">
                            <div><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Ranking</font></font>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td-rank">
                            <div class="td-div-1"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">1</font></font>
                            </div>
                        </td>
```

i was try to solve the problem with a different ways. But, i alwasy get`None` of `[]`.
What i did is like this :

```
        response.css('div.content-ranklist section.ranklist-table table').extract()
        response.css('div.content-ranklist section.ranklist-table table tr td.td-shopName').extract()
        response.css('//td[contains(@class, "td-shopName")]/text()').extract()
        response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr//td[@class='td-shopName']//a[@class='J_shopName']").extract()
```

The results always `None` and `[]`

this is the results

```
[]
=-=-=-=-
[]
=-=-=-=-
[]
=-=-=-=-
[]
=-=-=-=-
[]
=-=-=-=-
[]
=-=-=-=-
[]
=-=-=-=-
[]
=-=-=-=-
[]
=-=-=-=-
[]
=-=-=-=-
``

i was try to get this class :
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/40x4o.png
```

Comment: what you trying to extract?

Comment: the td inside the table

Comment: please show example output

Comment: i edited my question with the results after test my code

Comment: I'm asking you about the expected output from html source which you have here ! which text you want to extract !

Comment: inside the td with class td-shopName, there have a link, i want get the href. i will show the example code <a class="J_shopName" data-shopid="17637181" href="http://www.dianping.com/shop/17637181"><span class="td-div-shopName"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Quintiles Hotel and Teppanyaki</font></font></span></a>

Comment: check my answer below :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's `XHR` so here we go:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://www.dianping.com/shoplist/shopRank/pcChannelRankingV2?rankId=83f473b08cba2af53642a889d8802c50'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)  # wait 3 seconds for the site to load
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')

imgs = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'J_shopName'})
for img in imgs:
    print(img.get('href'))
```

output is:

```
http://www.dianping.com/shop/68193557
http://www.dianping.com/shop/112393652
http://www.dianping.com/shop/93227192
http://www.dianping.com/shop/132799437
http://www.dianping.com/shop/67917756
http://www.dianping.com/shop/17637181
http://www.dianping.com/shop/102198900
http://www.dianping.com/shop/130316435
http://www.dianping.com/shop/121684828
http://www.dianping.com/shop/130834244
http://www.dianping.com/shop/129948761
http://www.dianping.com/shop/73410505
http://www.dianping.com/shop/129320981
http://www.dianping.com/shop/111876029
http://www.dianping.com/shop/93659299
```

Comment: myhtml variable is a string, i don't know the scrapy can get the string like that. what i know is like ```response.css("table tr td a:J_shopname"). But, like i said, the results is None

Comment: use `requests` to parse the `html` source ! give me the link and i will edit my answer.

Comment: here the link : http://www.dianping.com/shoplist/shopRank/pcChannelRankingV2?rankId=83f473b08cba2af53642a889d8802c50

Comment: which class you want to parse ?

Comment: J_shopName class

Comment: there's no `J_shopName` in html source ! check by yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202700/discussion-between--c-and-stefani-johnsson).

Comment: @StefaniJohnsson check the new answer.